# How to hide . and .. folders in C?

Tags: c, file, dir, stat, readdir

I'm trying to list all folders and all files of a folder with the language C.

This is the following code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct dirent *direnp;
    struct stat filestat;
    DIR *dirp;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((dirp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((direnp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(direnp->d_name, &filestat);
        printf("%s\n", direnp->d_name); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After entering the cmd 
./file.c folder

The output from this code is:

```
folder1
folder2
file1.txt
..
.
file2.txt
```

I wish to remove this part:

```
..
.
```

So the output I wish is:

```
folder1
folder2
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

How do I hide the 3 dots?

*(Edit: There were some mistakes in the code. I corrected it)*

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do this is manually compare each entry's name with the strings "." and ".." and skip if they match

Comment: If (strcmp(dirp->dname,"..")) ...

Comment: Were ".." and "." really the 4th and 5th entries?

Comment: @chux well the positions of ".." and "." are random. this is why i want to hide them. In my case, they were at 4th and 5th for me.

Comment: In some _poor_ code, code have taken advantage that the first 2 entries are often "." and ".." and simply skipped the first 2 entries.  Good you are not doing the same.  Note: a folder might not have a ".".

Comment: @chux Just out of curiosity: Can you please direct me where to read more on folders not having a `.`?

Comment: @Palec Fat finger mistake on my part.  I should have said: Note: a folder might not have a "..".  e.g. a top-level folder

Comment: @chux That explains it. BTW POSIX forbids this. Base Definitions §4.12 Path Resolution says `The special filename dot-dot shall refer to the parent directory of its predecessor directory. As a special case, in the root directory, dot-dot may refer to the root directory itself.` and Rationale §4.12 says `Each directory has exactly one parent directory which is represented by the name dot-dot in the first directory. No other directory … is considered the parent directory by POSIX.1-2008.` and `What the filename dot-dot refers to relative to the root directory is implementation-defined.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply filter them in your while loop:

```
if (strcmp(direnp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(direnp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
   printf("%s\n", direnp->d_name);    
}
```

Comment: IMO the correct way would be to use the library functions( dirent.h ) to determine if the file is not a file or directory.

Comment: OP wants to list files **and** directories, but not the two special ones - afaik "." and ".." **are** normal directories (not pipes, not device files)

Comment: I said to determine if **not a file or directory** == anything else but a file or dir. So you can filter them.

Comment: @self But how would that allow to distinguish "." and ".."?

Comment: Read the library dirent.h. and look at types.

Comment: So, what do you think `type` will be for "." and ".."?

Comment: The code works correctly. Thank you Mr. Andreas. Just a little note, I forgot to type correctly d_name and the dirent name. Otherwise, everything works fine.

Comment: @LordRixuel Yes, I recognized the same when I compiled your code, but then you already fixed it in the question - I also adjusted my answer now to match your code. Hint: ideally post exactly the code which you run through your compiler - simply do a copy&paste from your code editor